# Invertibility of Block Matrix Partial Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, block-matrices, transpose, general-linear-group

Let $$M = \left[\begin{matrix}
M_{1,1} & M_{1,2} & \cdots & M_{1,n}\\
M_{2,1} & M_{2,2} & \cdots & M_{2,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
M_{n,1} & M_{n,2} & \cdots & M_{n,n}
\end{matrix}\right] \in \mathbb{F}_q^{nm \times nm}$$
where the $M_{i,j} \in \mathbb{F}_q^{m \times m}$ are invertible for all $i, j \in [n]$.

Consider the *partial transpose* $M^{\text{BT}}$:
$$M^{\text{BT}} = \left[\begin{matrix}
M_{1,1} & M_{2,1} & \cdots & M_{n,1}\\
M_{1,2} & M_{2,2} & \cdots & M_{n,2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
M_{1,n} & M_{2,n} & \cdots & M_{n,n}
\end{matrix}\right]$$
wherein the blocks' positions are transposed but the blocks themselves are not transposed.

Is it true that $\det(M) \neq 0$ if and only if $\det(M^{\text{BT}}) \neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is **No**.

A theorem of [Silvester](https://web.archive.org/web/20150318222335/http://www.ee.iisc.ernet.in/new/people/faculty/prasantg/downloads/blocks.pdf),

gives for $2\times 2$ block matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\ C & D \end{bmatrix}
$$
with $CD=DC$, we have
$$
\det M= \det (AD-BC).
$$

We try finding a counterexample in $2\times 2$ block matrices consisting of $2\times 2$ matrices.

Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1 \\0&1 \end{bmatrix}, \ B=\begin{bmatrix} 7 &-1\\-8&4\end{bmatrix}, \ C=\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}, D=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\ 1&1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

We have $CD=DC$. Then by Silvester's theorem,
$$
\det M=\det(AD-BC)=\det \begin{bmatrix} 3 &7 \\-3&-7\end{bmatrix}=0.
$$

However,
$$
M^{BT}=\begin{bmatrix}A & C\\ B & D \end{bmatrix}
$$
has
$$
\det M^{BT} = 3.
$$

Thus, by taking sufficiently large $q$, for example, $q=31$, we see that your question is answered negatively.